# unexpected behavior with listView and implicit intent

Tags: java, android

I'm developing a file explorer based on a listView.
The concept is simple : The listView is populated with the user's files inside the external and internal storage. The user can go through out the hierarchy by clicking on the listView's items or return to the parent by pressing the back button

If the item is a file ( like file.mp3 for e.g ) then an intent is sent to the system and the system shows a panel of other apps able to handle the file

Everything works fine but when the panel of other apps is showed and then closed ( by pressing the back button or sliding down ) , I need to press the back button twice to return to the parent file.. and this is the problem : I don't know why twice and why not only one..

I've figured out why but I don't get it...
What should I do to solve the problem ?

Here's the part of the code which occurs the problem

```
public class Frag2 extends Fragment {

private View root;

private File path;
private ArrayList<File> subPaths;

private ListView mListView;

private MyFileExplorerAdapter adapter;

public static boolean pause = false;

public void returnToParent(File f) {

    File parent = f.getParentFile();

    if(parent.getPath().equals("/mnt"))
        subPaths = getStoragesPath();

    else {
        path = parent;
        subPaths = updateSubPaths(path);
    }
    refresh();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    root = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.frag2,null);
    mListView = root.findViewById(R.id.listView);

    subPaths = getStoragesPath();
    refresh();

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener((adapterView, view, i, l) -> {

        path = subPaths.get(i);

        if(path.isDirectory()) {
            subPaths = updateSubPaths(path);
            refresh();
        }
        else {
            launchActivity();
        }

    });

}

private void refresh() {

    adapter = new MyFileExplorerAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.frag2, subPaths);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return root;
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    pause = false;
    if(path != null)
        refresh();

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    pause = true;
}

private boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {

    // get the external storage state
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    // return true if the external storage is mounted
    return state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
}

private ArrayList<File> getStoragesPath() {

    ArrayList<File> al = new ArrayList<>();

    if(isExternalStorageWritable())
        al.add(new File(Util.EXTERNAL_PATH));

    al.add(new File(Util.INTERNAL_PATH));

    return al;
}

private ArrayList<File> updateSubPaths(File currentPath) {

    ArrayList<File> al = new ArrayList<>();

    if(currentPath.listFiles() != null && OptionsActivity.isHiddenFilesVisible)
        al.addAll(Arrays.asList(currentPath.listFiles()));

    else if(currentPath.listFiles() != null && !OptionsActivity.isHiddenFilesVisible)
        al.addAll(Arrays.asList(currentPath.listFiles(new MyFileFilter())));

    return al;
}

private void launchActivity() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(path);

    String extension = Util.extension(path);

    if(Util.VIDEO.contains(extension))
        intent.setDataAndType(uri,"video/*");
    else if(Util.AUDIO.contains(extension))
        intent.setDataAndType(uri,"audio/*");
    else if(Util.IMAGE.contains(extension))
        intent.setDataAndType(uri,"image/*");
    else if(Util.TEXT.contains(extension))
        intent.setDataAndType(uri,"text/*");
    else if(Util.APPLICATION.contains(extension))
        intent.setDataAndType(uri,"application/*");

    getActivity().startActivity(intent);

}

public File getPath() {
    return path;
}

}
```

Comment: Does someone have an idea ?